Fill DTO fields including custom enum types using projection Criteria Query API
I have the following DTO:
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDto {
    private Integer field1;
    private CustomEnum field2;
}

The custom enum:
public enum CustomEnum {
    ONE("One"),
    TWO("Two");

    private final String name;

    CustomEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static CustomEnum fromString(String value) {
        Optional<CustomEnum> found = Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(customEnum -> customEnum.toString().equals(value))
                .findFirst();

        return typeFound.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

So, I'm using the Criteria Query API to query and return results of DTO type using projection:
final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Myto> cq = cb.createQuery(MyDto.class);
.
.
.

cq.select(
    cb.construct(
        MyDto.class,
        ...,
        cb.selectCase()
            .when(<some predicate>, CustomEnum.ONE)
            .otherwise(CustomEnum.TWO)
            .alias("field2")
    )
);

.
.
.
final TypedQuery<MyDto> query = em.createQuery(cq);
return query.getResultList();

But when executing the code, I get the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.JdbcMapping.getJdbcValueBinder()"
because "jdbcMapping" is null

How can I fix this?

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756529/npe-getjdbcvaluebinder
